# How to disable networking traffic / connections in Nix language in Nixos?

Tags: networking, nix, nixos

Have searched https://nixos.org/nixos/options.html#networking for networking options. And I have not found something that may achieve this:

I would like a configuration which ensures that users don't have any network traffic.
As it would be a nix generation, running `$ nixos-rebuild switch` on a `configuration.nix` file without this network option, could put the computer network communication back to normal.

I have tried mannually calling `$ sudo systemctl stop network-manager`, but it had no results.

Similarily, nothing seemed to change when I tried modifying this in `configuration.nix` and then `$ nixos-rebuild switch`

```
networking.networkManager.enable = false
```

Any idea ?
Should I manually deal with each of the network interfaces ?

Comment: To be clear, there are *lots* of different ways networking can be managed, and `networkManager` is just one of them. So turning off one of several network management subsystems is not the same as turning off networking.

Comment: Anyhow -- do you need something that can be plopped into *any* other configuration, or only a specific configuration? If the former, it's arguably too broad to be within our guidelines for "reasonable scope" (if it's on-topic at all, vs being a better fit for [unix.se]). If the latter, we need to know what other network-related configuration is present.

Comment: ...so, hopefully the answer I've provided works. That said, I've also voted-to-close as off-topic, being a question less about the Nix language and more about operating-system configuration in NixOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*With everything else at defaults*, this may be as simple as:

```
networking.useDHCP = false;
networking.interfaces = {};
```

Of course, you could also go more heavy-handed -- putting all your network hardware into the `blacklistedKernelModules` list, f/e -- and personally, I'd recommend that.

Comment: `blacklistedKernelModules` is the way to go